# Broke string into vars with variable position

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I need to broke a string into some vars but its order is not fixed as the exemple:

```
$string = "name='John';phone='555-5555';city='oakland';";
$string2 = "city='oakland';phone='555-5555';name='John';";
$string3 = "phone='555-5555';name='John';city='oakland';";
```

so I need to broke the strings into:

```
$name
$phone
$city
```

if the position would be fixed i could use explode and call for the array key that i need like

```
$brokenString = explode("'",$string);

$name = $brokenString[1];
$phone = $brokenString[3];
$city = $brokenString[5];
```

however how could I do it with variable position??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to make the position same always for all string variables.

```
<?php
$string = "name='John';phone='555-5555';city='oakland';";
$string2 = "city='oakland';phone='555-5555';name='John';";
$string3 = "phone='555-5555';name='John';city='oakland';";
$array = explode(';',$string3);
sort($array);
$array = array_filter($array); # remove the empty element
foreach($array as $value){
    $split = explode('=',$value);
    $result[$split[0]] = $split[1]; 
}
extract($result); # extract result as php variables
echo "\$city = $city; \$name = $name; \$phone = $phone";
?>
```

**EDIT:** As using `extract()` is generally not a good idea.You can use simple `foreach()` instead of `extract()`,

```
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
  $$k = $v;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/RB8pT

Comment: @NigelRen agreed on sir.  Added an edited version also.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler method, but what I've done is created an array `$stringVariables` which holds the exploded strings.

This array is then looped through and `strpos` is used in each element in the exploded string array to see if it contains 'city', 'phone', or 'name'. Depending on which one, it's added to an array which holds either all the names, cities or phone numbers.

```
$stringVariables = array();
$phones = array();
$names = array();
$cities = array();
$stringVariables[] = explode(";",$string);
$stringVariables[] = explode(";",$string2);
$stringVariables[] = explode(";",$string3);
foreach($stringVariables as $stringVariable) {
   foreach($stringVariable as $partOfString) {
      if(strpos($partOfString, "name=") !== false) {
         $names[] = $partOfString;
      }else if(strpos($partOfString, "city=") !== false) {
         $cities[] = $partOfString;
      }else if(strpos($partOfString, "phone=") !== false) {
         $phones[] = $partOfString;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to convert it into something that can be parsed as a URL string.

First part is to change the values and , from `'John',` to `John&` using a regex (`'([^']+)';` which looks for a `'` up to a `'` followed by a `;`), then parse the result (using `parse_str()`)...

```
$string = "name='John';phone='555-5555';city='oakland';";
$string = preg_replace("/'([^']+)';/","$1&", $string);
echo $string.PHP_EOL;

parse_str( $string, $values );

print_r($values);
```

gives the output of

```
name=John&phone=555-5555&city=oakland&
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [phone] => 555-5555
    [city] => oakland
)
```

or just using regex's...

```
preg_match_all("/(\w*)?='([^']+)';/", $string, $matches);

print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```